# Dividing the website into 2 parts with separate scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

The website has 2 elements, left and right part both taking 50%

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Each one has a box inside, just so its easy to see where the part currently is in terms of scrolling

```
body {
            display: flex;
        }
        .wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        .left,.right {
            height: 150%;
            width: 50%;
            background: #eee;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            position: absolute;

        }
        .right {
            background: #222;
            left: 50%
        }
        .box {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background: #bbb;
        }
```

On left or right div click i 'open' it to the full screen width with jquery, removing the overflow:hidden of parent div to enable scrolling.

```
let i = 0;
        $('.left').click(function(){
            if($(this).width() / $(document).width() == 0.5 && i == 0){
                i = 1
                    $(this).css({'z-index':'2'}).animate({'width':'100%'},300)
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        $('.wrapper').css({'overflow-y':'auto'})
                    },300)
                i = 0
            }

            if($(this).width() / $(document).width() > 0.8 && i == 0){
                i = 1
                    $(this).animate({'width':'50%'},300)
                    $('.wrapper').css({'overflow-y':'hidden'})
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        $(this).css({'z-index':'0'})
                    },300)
                i = 0
            }
        })
        $('.right').click(function(){
            if($(this).width() / $(document).width() == 0.5 && i == 0){
                i = 1
                    $(this).css({'z-index':'2'}).animate({'width':'100%','left':'0'},300)
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        $('.wrapper').css({'overflow-y':'auto'})
                    },300)
                i = 0
            }

            if($(this).width() / $(document).width() > 0.8 && i == 0){
                i = 1 
                    $(this).animate({'width':'50%','left':'50%'},300)
                    $('.wrapper').css({'overflow-y':'hidden'})
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        $(this).css({'z-index':'0'})
                },300)
                i = 0
            }
        })
```

What i want to achieve, is individual left and right divs scrolling, i've tried assigning possition : fixed to div that is not visible, when one of 2 is opened, which does make it stay in place. Hoever, when i try to open the position:fixed div, assigning its original absolute position back, it just jumps to where the 'last scrolling point' of the other div was. Any ideas on how to make the independently scrollable ?

Comment: I edit my answer. I believe i have what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>File compare</title>
    <style>
        .flex {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .flex>.split {
            height: 100vh;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        .gutter.gutter-horizontal {
            cursor: ew-resize;
        }

        .gutter {
            background-color: #eee;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 50%;
        }

        .gutter.gutter-horizontal {
            background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAeCAYAAADkftS9AAAAIklEQVQoU2M4c+bMfxAGAgYYmwGrIIiDjrELjpo5aiZeMwF+yNnOs5KSvgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
        }

        .heading {
            padding: 15px;
            background: #eeeeee;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #0062cc;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex">
        <div id="one" class="split">
            <div class="heading">
                Column one
            </div>
            <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. I
                t was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pas
                sages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including version
                s of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

            <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. I
                t was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pas
                sages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including version
                s of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. I
                t was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pas
                sages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including version
                s of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. I
                t was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pas
                sages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including version
                s of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="split">
            <div class="heading">
                Column two
            </div>
            <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. I
                t was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pas
                sages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including version
                s of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. I
                t was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pas
                sages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including version
                s of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. I
                t was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pas
                sages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including version
                s of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. I
                t was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pas
                sages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including version
                s of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/split.js/1.5.11/split.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Split(['#one', '#two'], {
            sizes: [50, 50]
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial setup meant, that left or right div was overflowing the parent wrapper, which was not what i've needed. So i've came to using `overflow:scroll` as was suggested, but having default state as `hidden`

```
.left,.right {
            position: absolute;
            height: 150%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            display: flex;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
```

and changing it to scroll after the animation on click `$(this).css({'overflow-y':'scroll'})`